# Is the solution of Rudin Ex. 2.8 in solutions manual corrcet?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

> From Rudin Ex. $2.8$:
>
> Is every point of every open set $E\subset{R}^{2}$ a limit point of $E$?

The solutions manual gives:

[image]

However, I found that if $E$ consists of two open sets and such $(x_{1},x_{2})$ and $(y_{1},y_{2})$ are from the two open sets respectively, then $(z_{1},z_{2})=(x_{1}+\frac{1}{2}\min (r,s),x_{2})$ may not belong to $E$.

For a simple example in $R^{1}$:

Let $E=(a_{1},a_{2}+\frac{1}{n})\cup(b_{1}-\frac{1}{n},b_{2})$ and $s>b_{1}-a_{2}$ where $a_{1}<a_{2}+\frac{1}{n}<b_{1}-\frac{1}{n}<b_{2}$ and $n$ is a large number. Then for $r>0$, $c=a_{2}+\frac{1}{2}\min(r,s)$ may be dropped into the middle area, namely $c\in(a_{2}+\frac{1}{n},b_{1}-\frac{1}{n})$ but $c\notin E$.

So why does the solutions manual say $(z_{1},z_{2})=(x_{1}+\frac{1}{2}\min (r,s),x_{2})$ belongs to $E$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt {(z_1-x_1)^{2}+(z_2-x_2)^{2}} =\frac  1 2 \min\{r,s\} <s$ so $(z_1,z_2) \in E$. There is no  mistake in the manual.

$s$ is chosen in a particular way and that condition is not met in your example.

Comment: To the proposer: You cannot take any $s>0$ that you want ("Let $s>b_1-a_2$...") . Given $p\in E,$ the value of $s$ must be small enough that every point less than distance $s$  from $ p$ also belongs to $E$. How big $s$ can be depends on $p$ (and on $E$).............+1

Answer (score 0):

The proof is correct. Here's a different way to present the same idea.

First a useful lemma: *if $A\subseteq B$ and $x$ is a limit point of $A$, then $x$ is a limit point of $B$*. The proof is just applying definitions.

Now, if $E$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x\in E$, then there exists $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)$ (the open ball centered at $x$ of radius $r$) is contained in $E$. Thus we are reduced to prove that $x$ is a limit point of $B(x,r)$. A neighborhood $U$ of $x$ contains a ball $B(x,s)$, so $U\cap B(x,r)\supseteq B(x,s)\cap B(x,r)=B(x,\min(s,r))$, which contains points distinct from $x$.